# Multiple addants additionin a query using python

Tags: python

I want to write a code where user inputs addants to be added and my code will return the answer accurately. The difference is that I want to give the user the freedom of adding infinity things together. The language is python.

```
Sample
Input             Output
1+1+1               3
1+1                 2
2+5+6               13
6+4+5+7             22
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: the user inputs are in a single line or in mutliple lines?

Comment: What exactly is your question about this? Was there a particular problem with the code you have tried to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the user inputs data in a single line with all integers separated by a whitespace, you can try:

```
sum(list(map(int,input().split(" "))))
```

- Read input line
- split elements on ws
- convert into list of integers
- sum the elements inside the list